# ASP.NET MVC not rendering view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following

### NewsFeedController.cs

```
public class NewsFeedController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TwitterCallback(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
    {
        var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token };

        string Key = "";
        string Secret = "";

        try
        {
            TwitterService service = new TwitterService(Key, Secret);

            OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);

            service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);

            VerifyCredentialsOptions option = new VerifyCredentialsOptions();

            TwitterUser user = service.VerifyCredentials(option);
            String name = user.ScreenName;

            ViewData["user_name"] = name;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

with the following

### TwitterCallback.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TwitterCallback";
}

<h2>Hello, @ViewData["user_name"]</h2>
```

### RouteConfig.cs

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

My problem is that the `NewsFeedController` doesn't render anything. It executes `TwitterCallback` without throwing exception but it doesn't return any view. If I change the method type to String and return `ViewData["user_name"]`, the correct name is displayed. Therefore, I think I have somehow declared the view the wrong way.

I just started getting my hands on with mvc so I apologise if this may sound like a beginner question.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

*Project Structure:*

[image: Project Structure]

This is what I get: (no error message, nothing)

[image]

EDIT: 
This is how the callback URL is called: (where TwitterAuth is a method in HomeController.cs and is called when the user clicks the login button)

```
public ActionResult TwitterAuth()
        {
            string Key = "";
            string Secret = "";

            TwitterService service = new TwitterService(Key, Secret);

            OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1:8080/NewsFeed/TwitterCallback");

            Uri uri = service.GetAuthenticationUrl(requestToken);

            return Redirect(uri.ToString());
        }
```

If i just paste the redirect URL in my browser I get that:
[image]

EDIT2: Thank you all for your help. I still don't understand why it didn't work in the first place (as Andrei was saying in the comments, it's not a .net problem) I changed my twitter library to tweetinvi and now it works.

Comment: Did you try explicitly passing the viewname like `return View('TwitterCallback');` ?

Comment: what do you see ? you said not rendering the view then what to you see in response ? like 404, 403 or some error view ?

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Are you getting an empty view with just "Hello" text or a 404?? .

Comment: @kayess I have tried your suggestion but I get 'too many characters in string literal' so I changed it to return View("TwitterCallback"); but I have the same problem as before

Comment: @Krishna no, it's just a simple blank screen which is what I don't understand (i'll add a screenshot to my post)

Comment: How are you calling this action? Which URL are you navigating to?

Comment: put a break point in cshtml you will know

Comment: @Andrei This one: http://127.0.0.1:8080/NewsFeed/TwitterCallback?oauth_token=xxxxx&oauth_verifier=xxxx

Comment: @Krishna I tried now, I put a breakpoint in both the NewsFeed/Index.cshtml and TwitterCallback.cshtml but none of them are called

Comment: remove viewdata and just put a static content and see

Comment: Check my answer. You should not use @ before using ViewData

Comment: Talking about break points, did you debug the TwitterCallback action to make sure `return View()` is called as expected?

Comment: @Andrei yes, it gets there ... as I was saying in my post, if I change the method type to string and return let's say return "testing"; then that message is displayed

Comment: @KeykoYume, considering your last update, this issue has nothing to do with asp.net mvc. It has to do with the way you are doing twitter auth locally though, but I don't know enough here to advise